# How to get scrollY point in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm building a header and I want to **hide the header content** **UNTIL** the user scrolls down to the certain point.

(My Approach)

1. Get scrollY position (How much did user scroll vertically from top?)
2. if scrollY is greater than 50
3. show the header name.

Here is render() method. I manually built header. I'm getting scrollY value and set it to this.state.scrollY

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={styles.header}>
      {this._renderHeader(profile.username)}
    </View>
    <ScrollView style={styles.root}
      onScroll={(event)=>{this.setState({scrollY: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y})}}>
    // setting this.state.scrollY for scroll Y position
    ...
```

Here is _renderHeader function. (rendering header)

```
  _renderHeader = (username) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.headerLayout}>
        <View rkCardHeader style={styles.left}>
          ...
          <View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            {this._renderUsername(username)}
            // I want to show this string ONLY IF user 
            // scrolls down the window to the certain point.
          </View>
        ....
      </View>
    );
  }
```

(Here is the problem) This doesn't render only  or it doesn't trigger _renderUsername.

```
  _renderUsername = (username) => {
    let show = (this.state.scrollY > 50) ? true : false;
    if(show) {
      return (
        <RkText rkType='header3'>{username}</RkText>
      );
    } else {
      return <View />
    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://github.com/shubhnik/react-native-animation3

Comment: That looks ok but I don't need the animation. I will edit whole question. I think my question was too abroad

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can keep a track of scrollY in redux store and map it to the header component.

While rendering the header component use ternary expression to decide whether to render or not.

For example - 
(From the store you will get the value this.props.scrollY)

```
render() {
  return (
     {this.props.scrollY > 50 ? <AppHeader /> : ""}
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: But how do we get scrollY??? I edited whole question. I want to accept your answer if you can explain it.